# Pandas & NumPy on Pythonista iPad App

Tags: python, ipad, numpy, pandas, pythonista

Is Pythonista a viable tool for data analysis? I'm looking to learn Python so I can break into QA at my company, and I'm debating whether I should go with a Mac and Sublime Text, or an iPad Pro and Pythonista.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

If you want to make data analysis, you should make that with a computer. The power from a tablet is not enough to make analysis.

Comment: I figured, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: @Macinboss Don't forget to vote answer ;)

Comment: that is a strange comment... I use it all the time for testing purposes. it has an incredible library of modules pre-installed.  It is obviously designed with a market in mind for a myriad of apple devices.  You open up the debate about which hardware operating system one should be using, which is a no-win situation.

Comment: @DanPatterson That's interesting! So are you able to transfer and use the scripts written in Pythonista?

What I mean by that is, can I send them to a Mac to be run, or is it confined to be used with the iPad?

Comment: I copy/send everything to one of the 'cloud' options depending on where it needs to go... usually OneDrive for my pc but anywhere, even email. then I use it there.  Bringing the files in is a similar process.  That way I can program where ever I am with my iPad.  apparently you can use it on any "iThingy" even the phone.  I have no complaints, except python 3 isn't out yet, but very soon based on the pythonista forum.  As long as you know the differences between 2 and 3, there are no issues.. I am py-lingual in any event

Comment: Thank's @DanPatterson that's extremely helpful!

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I've removed the acceptance of the answer. user1121588's response was spot on!